# JFR consumes too much memory, causing OOM

Tags: java, memory, jvm, out-of-memory, jfr

we attempted to enable the JFR (Java Flight Recorder) feature in our production environment. We used the following startup parameters:

```
-XX:StartFlightRecording=disk=true,dumponexit=true,name=profile_online,filename=/tmp/profile_`hostname`-`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S`.jfr,maxsize=4096m,maxage=2d,settings=/opt/app/WEB-INF/tars/prod/custom.jfc,path-to-gc-roots=false -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=maxchunksize=32m
```

We were using JDK version 11.0.14, and the garbage collector in use was G1.

After enabling the above JFR configuration on one of our applications, we encountered bulk Out of Memory (OOM) issues on 7 machines four days later.

We reviewed the monitoring data and found that heap conditions appeared relatively normal. However, we noticed that the mem rss usage, which was around 15GB (peaking at 16GB) before the recent deployment, increased to approximately 15.5GB after the deployment.

To address the issue, we attempted to analyze it using Native Memory Tracking (NMT) and discovered that after four days, the memory overhead for Tracing metrics had reached around 400MB. We suspect that Tracing metrics may include memory overhead from JFR.

We are perplexed about why bulk OOM issues occurred precisely four days after the deployment and whether JFR's memory consumption is related to runtime duration. We are also curious about the primary sources of JFR's memory overhead and whether there is a way to estimate JFR's memory overhead based on startup parameters.

Comment: Any kind of profiling will have an overhead. I'm not sure about JFR but usually this kind of tool is not meant to be executed continuously. Why you were expecting otherwise? Also what is the memory configuration of the JVM? Maybe it is too tight?  What OOM issues? Provide details and complete errors. And what is the usage of memory pools with and without JFR?

Comment: JFR has been designed to be always on. Sounds like a bug, JFR should use perhaps 50 MB. Have you tried to upgrade to the latest JDK 11 release? Do you create your own custom JFR events?

Comment: Our pod limit 16GB,JVM options: -Xmx 12GB,-Xms 12GB.Before enabling JFR, the application's RSS 
 was consistently at 15GB. However, from the day we enabled JFR until the fourth day when the RSS usage became excessively high, it kept increasing. According to our JFR configuration with maxsize=4096m,maxage=2d, JFR's memory usage should actually follow a two-day cycle. This behavior doesn't align with our expected configuration.

Comment: We haven't customized any JFR events; we simply disabled the collection of some events based on the default.jfc provided by the JDK. Additionally, adjusting the JDK's minor version might be a significant effort for us. We would prefer to understand the root cause because our intention is to have JFR enabled on most of our applications. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose. The amount of memory used depends on the number of classes being touched, depth of stack traces, number of threads etc., but 400 MB sound too much. If it's a native memory leak, it could potentially be the OldObjectSample event. The memory management of it is complex and there have been issues with it in the past. You could try to disable it in .jfc file.

Comment: Furthermore, we have approximately 2,000 threads running on a single pod in our production environment. Could this potentially result in significant memory overhead for JFR? (Although this doesn't explain why the memory usage doesn't follow the expected 2-day cycle as per the configuration.)

Comment: An 8 KB buffer is created for every thread, so that's not more than 16 MB.

Comment: Thanks, I have followed your advice and closed the OldObjectSample event. I am currently monitoring rss in the mirror environment.

Comment: I observed a noticeable slowdown in RSS growth after disabling `OldObjectSample`, which was a pleasant surprise. Additionally, I noticed that the few bug proposals related to `OldObjectSample` on bugs.openjdk.org don't align with my situation. Is there a way to gain more detailed insights into the overhead of various JFR events beyond what NMT provides? (Since our memory leak issue has a lengthy cycle, we'd like to further pinpoint it from the metrics perspective. I'm also personally curious about this.)

Comment: NMT would be best. It might be possible to create a custom built JDK to collect  additional information, but you would need to change the source code or file a ticket with Oracle (if you have a support contract).